# Unable to Display Data from database in Table

Tags: php, jquery

I have been trying to output the result via `.$result['name'].` but of no use.

Below is my code:

```php
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db("amityada_admission") or die(mysql_error());

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>Search Inquiry</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h3>Search Result</h3>
<p>
  <?php
    $query = $_POST['query']; 

    $min_length = 5;    

    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student_admission
            WHERE (`mobile` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`university` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 
            echo "<table>";
            while ($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($raw_results))  {

                echo <<<EOD
<h2 style="background-color:#009; color:#FFF; padding: 10px; alignment-adjust:baseline">Student Admission Form</h2>
<div align="center">
  <table width="90%" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" scope="row"><h3 align="left" style="background-color:#F39; color:#FFF; padding: 10px">Admission Form for | $name | Session 2015-2016</h3></th>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="7">$file</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" scope="row" style="background-color:#009; color:#FFF; padding:4px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif" ><div align="left"><strong>Personal Details</strong></div></th>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="29%" scope="row"><div align="left">Student Name</div></th>
      <td width="9%"><div align="left">$name</div></td>
      <td width="25%"><div align="left"><strong>Fathers Name</strong></div></td>
      <td width="13%"><div align="left">$fname</div></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">Mothers Name</div></th>
      <td><div align="left">$mname</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"><strong>Date of Birth</strong></div></td>
      <td><div align="left">$dob</div></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">Mobile Number</div></th>
      <td><div align="left">$mobile</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"><strong>Email ID</strong></div></td>
      <td><div align="left">$email</div></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">Gender</div></th>
      <td><div align="left">$gender</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"><strong>Marital Status</strong></div></td>
      <td><div align="left">$maritalstatus</div></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">Employed</div></th>
      <td><div align="left">$employed</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"><strong>Course Type</strong></div></td>
      <td><div align="left">$coursetype</div></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6" scope="row" style="background-color:#009; color:#FFF; padding:4px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif"><div align="left">Educational Details</div></th>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left"><strong>Current Education</strong></div></th>
      <td><div align="left">$current_educational_details</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"><strong>Course Applied For</strong></div></td>
      <td><div align="left">$course</div></td>
      <td width="11%"><div align="left"><strong>Specialization</strong></div></td>

      <td width="13%"><div align="left">$specialization</div></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">Lateral Entry</div></th>
      <td><div align="left">$lateralentry</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"><strong>Lateral Entry In</strong></div></td>
      <td><div align="left">$lateral_entry_in</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"></div></td>
      <td><div align="left"></div></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6" scope="row" style="background-color:#009; color:#FFF; padding:4px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif"><div align="left">Correspondence Address</div>       <div align="left"></div>        <div align="left"></div>        <div align="left"></div>        <div align="left"></div>        <div align="left"></div></th>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">Address</div></th>
      <td colspan="5"><div align="left">$corr_add</div>        <div align="left"></div>        <div align="left"></div>        <div align="left"></div>        <div align="left"></div></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">Country</div></th>
      <td><div align="left">$countryId</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"><strong>State</strong></div></td>
      <td><div align="left">$stateId</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"><strong>City</strong></div></td>
      <td><div align="left">$cityId</div></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6" scope="row" style="background-color:#009; color:#FFF; padding:4px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif"><div align="left">Payment Option</div>        <div align="left"></div>        <div align="left"></div>        <div align="left"></div>        <div align="left"></div>        <div align="left"></div></th>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">Payment Mode</div></th>
      <td><div align="left">$payment_method</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"><strong>Payment Option</strong></div></td>
      <td><div align="left">$feesinfull</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"></div></td>
      <td><div align="left"></div></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">Complete Fees</div></th>
      <td><div align="left">$coursefees</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"><strong>Full Fees Paid</strong></div></td>
      <td><div align="left">$fullfees</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"><strong>Discount</strong></div></td>
      <td><div align="left">$discount</div></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6" scope="row" style="background-color:#009; color:#FFF; padding:4px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif"><div align="left">Installment Options</div>        <div align="left"></div>        <div align="left"></div>        <div align="left"></div>        <div align="left"></div>        <div align="left"></div></th>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">Installment 1</div></th>
      <td><div align="left">$installment1</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"><strong>Paid On</strong></div></td>
      <td><div align="left">$ins1</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"></div></td>
      <td><div align="left"></div></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">Installment 2</div></th>
      <td><div align="left">$installment2</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"><strong>Paid On</strong></div></td>
      <td><div align="left">$ins2</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"></div></td>
      <td><div align="left"></div></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">Installment 3</div></th>
      <td><div align="left">$installment3</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"><strong>Paid On</strong></div></td>
      <td><div align="left">$ins3</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"></div></td>
      <td><div align="left"></div></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">Installment 4</div></th>
      <td><div align="left">$installment4</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"><strong>Paid On</strong></div></td>
      <td><div align="left">$ins4</div></td>
      <td><div align="left"></div></td>
      <td><div align="left"></div></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">Installment 5</div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">$installment5</div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left"><strong>Paid On</strong></div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">$ins5</div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">Installment 6</div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">$installment6</div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left"><strong>Paid On</strong></div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">$ins6</div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">Installment 7</div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">$installment7</div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left"><strong>Paid On</strong></div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">$ins7</div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">Installment 8</div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">$installment8</div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left"><strong>Paid On</strong></div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">$ins8</div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">Installment 9</div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">$installment9</div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left"><strong>Paid On</strong></div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">$ins9</div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">Installment 10</div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">$installment10</div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left"><strong>Paid On</strong></div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left">$installment10</div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
      <th scope="row"><div align="left"></div></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6" scope="row"><div align="left">
        <p>This is Just an Admission Form filled for the purpose of Applying for the University. This is not an University Admission Form and Should only be traeted for Pune Institute Admission Purpose. Any Changes or Request for Updation of Student Details of Change of University has to be Submitted to the IT Admin through mail on <strong>info@puneinstitute.org</strong></p>
      </div></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6" scope="row" style="background-color:grey; color:white; padding: 7px">&copy; <a href="#">Ankit</a> 2003-2015 | Powered By &copy; <a href="#">Diaphram</a> 2011-2015 </th>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>

EOD;


        }
               echo "</table>";

        }
        else{ 
            echo "No Results Found";
        }

    }
    else{ 
        echo "Oops !! You Pressed Refresh Button or Minimum Input Value is $min_length";

    }
?>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it should be `$results['name']`

Comment: what's the error here? Please show us.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/amityadav/public_html/admissionform/result.php on line 48

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: i will change it to PDO

Answer (score 2):

You're setting row data to `$results`, but never using it. 
(In here:  `while ($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($raw_results))  {` )

Either use `extract($results)` after the above code to use column names as variables like in your code or use variables as `$results['name']`.

Comment: Tried that as well, but its returning to echo "Oops !! You Pressed Refresh Button or Minimum Input Value is $min_length";

Comment: Tried that as well, but its returning to echo "Oops !! You Pressed Refresh Button or Minimum Input Value is $min_length"; Same Code is working fine if i am using if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 

                echo "<table>";
    while ($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($raw_results))
    {
                        
                echo "
  <tr>
    <th colspan=\"2\">Student Details of ".$results['student_name']."</th>
  </tr>

Answer (score 1):

Try `mysql_fetch_array()` instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc()` then print the result with the index no of column like the following

`$result[0]`

For Example if the `name` column is the 1st column in your table then use `$result[0]` similarly if it is 2nd, then use `$result[1]`

Try this and let me know

Comment: It simply won't work, since he's using `mysql_fetch_assoc`. This only returns an array with column names as keys.

Comment: Thank you for the information @scosu I have edited my answer

Comment: Edited and Used mysql_fetch_array instead of mysql_fetch assoc and tried to get the data via $results[7]. Its is returning to "Oops !! You Pressed Refresh Button or Minimum Input Value is 5"

Answer (score 0):

You should have:

`$name` here should be `$results['name']`

`$file` here should be `$results['file']`

`$fname` here should be `$results['fname']`

`$mname` here should be `$results['mname']`

`$mobile` here should be `$results['mobile']`

and so on with the other data on your table.

---

And also delete one of your `</table>` cause in your code you have 2 of it.